# Как обратиться напрямую к sql-выборке, полученной через JOIN?

Tags: sql

Есть запрос:

```sql
SELECT (book.amount+supply.amount) AS Количество
FROM book INNER JOIN supply USING (author_id)
```

Cуществует ли возможность как-то обратиться по имени к выборке, созданной JOIN'ом?
Грубо говоря, хочу вместо

```sql
SELECT (book.amount+supply.amount) AS Количество
```

написать что-то вроде

```sql
SELECT (SUM(Таблица_Созданная_Выборкой_Через_JOIN.amount) ) AS Количество
```

Вероятно, вопрос крайне тривиальный, но я только начинаю знакомиться с SQL.

Заранее спасибо!

p.s. может показаться некорректным замена book.amount+supply.amount на SUM(amount), но в контексте таблицы, с которой я имею дело - оно имеет место. Вопрос именно в том, как обратиться к выборке ?

Comment: У Вас не получается создать адекватную модель. Так что выкладывайте реальные структуру, пример данных и нужный для этих данных ответ. Вот лишние поля и их значения - это удалите.

Comment: А почему не достаточно `sum(book.amount+supply.amount)` ? Если там какая то очень сложная формула, то надо завернуть ваш запрос в еще один и там уже можно оперировать посчитанными значениями, вроде `select sum(amount) from (select book.amount+supply.amount as amount ....) x`

Answer (score 0):

Большинство SQL-серверов поддерживают вложенные подзапросы

```
SELECT (SUM(Таблица_Созданная_Выборкой_Через_JOIN.amount) ) AS Количество
FROM (
  SELECT (book.amount+supply.amount) AS amount
  FROM book INNER JOIN supply USING (author_id)
) AS Таблица_Созданная_Выборкой_Через_JOIN
```

Также если вам нужно один и тот же подзапрос использовать часто, в разных запросах, то можно создать представление (`VIEW`). Синтаксис сильно зависит от используемой СУБД, подробности смотрите в справке.